# sudo on AIX 7.2

Tags: software-installation, sudo, aix

Does anyone know where I can get the package to install sudo on AIX 7.2?
I am looking at https://www.sudo.ws/download.html and see packages only until 7.1.
I heard sudo support for AIX 7.2 has been removed.
I wasn't able to locate any IBM docs for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Download the IBM sudo RPM from [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html), specifically at: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/sudo/sudo-1.8.20p2-4.aix6.1.ppc.rpm

The package will install and run just fine on AIX 7.2. IBM has a strong history of [binary compatibility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.install/binary_compatability.htm) between versions of AIX.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff . Is sudo officially supported on AIX 7.2 ?

Comment: While I've never encountered a bug or a support issue with it, it is provided ["as a convenience to IBM customers. IBM does not own the Code, and did not develop or exhaustively test the Code. IBM does not provide support for the Code ... No Warranty: The Code is provided "As is.""](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/license.html). The [FAQ](http://ftp.software.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/FAQ) refers questions to a [forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=2eb0f36d-9534-471b-8b27-c21e6c5b9b2b&ps) which I have not needed to visit.

Answer (score 1):

AIX Toolbox web link --> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html

ftp link --> ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/

Those two libraries are getting shipped with openldap rpm.

I suggest you to use yum, otherwise you will have to manually figure out the dependencies for openldap.

Go through this document on how to configure yum in AIX --> https://developer.ibm.com/articles/configure-yum-on-aix/

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8ac40bd8-265f-41a8-a5d2-0a28e57275c4